# How do I visualize CNN on pytorch

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

I've just learned a little about pytorch. I built a CNN to calculate the effects of various optimization algorithms with the official documents of pytorch (I've just finished from SGD to adagrad). However, most of the official documents and tutorial videos ended when the accuracy and time-consuming were calculated, and the code of model visualization ，I had no idea at all. I would like to ask  what is used for visualization similar to the following two figures. Is it Matplotlib pyplot or the visualization tool corresponding to pytorch?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJ9fa.png)

Answer (score 1):

I can not tell you what library is used to generate the plot you linked to.
There are plenty of options, all of which you can use once you have the data.
One of these options is matplotlib. Others include using Matlab or pgfplots if you want to include your plots in a LaTeX document. These are the tools I use somewhat frequently. They are purely subjective choices.

However, pytorch also supports tensorboard, which is especially useful for live tracking of the training progress.
Have a look at this tutorial: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/tensorboard_with_pytorch.html

Answer (score 0):

it looks like matplotlib pyplot to me. While training, you can store all the loss values and accuracy values and plot them after the network is trained.